# External IP was pending while applied service.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, ip, kubectl, minikube, vcluster

I had installed [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/), [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), [vcluster](https://www.vcluster.com/docs/getting-started/setup).

> I had created a namespace(a-team) and applied a service.yaml file to create a service in the namespace. In service.yaml file I used **type: LoadBalancer** and **type: NodePort**. But the external IP is not generating
> [image: terminal log]

**service.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: a-team-cluster
spec:
  selector:
    app: vcluster
    release: a-team
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**values.yaml file**

```
syncer:
  extraArgs:
  - --tls-san=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have a loadbalancer implementation running. For minikube this could be `minikube tunnel` in a separate terminal window.

Comment: we have to expose our kubectl deployment, then it works,
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel